# Coloured background on part of a page

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, backgrounds, eso-pic

I am trying to colour the background of the top fifth of a page. I thought that I should use [eso-pic](https://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) and [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) for this, and came up with the following:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle, fill = blue, minimum width = \paperwidth, minimum height = \paperheight * 0.2] {};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

This adds the background to the bottom of the page. How can I put it at the top?

I would also be happy to hear suggestions about how to do this whole thing better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the tikz picture inside the `AtPageUpperLeft` command and set the the node anchor to `north west`

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
%
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\AtPageUpperLeft{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\node[rectangle, fill = blue, minimum width = \paperwidth,outer sep=0pt, minimum height = 0.2\paperheight, anchor =north west]{};
\end{tikzpicture}}
}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain why I need `remember picture` and `overlay`? And an `outer sep` of 0pt? It seems that I get the result that I want with only `overlay`.

Comment: @twsh for the `outer sep` option try for example `outer sep=1cm` to see the effect. For the `overlay` option I don't know why it is required bu without it this will not work. For the `remember picture` option we don't need it at all and I will remove it .

Comment: @twsh an edit has been made. The correct command to use to have the picture on every page and not only on the current one is `\AddToShipoutPictureBG` without the "*"

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use a hammersledge like tikz for that: a simple coloured rule will do:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
%
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
\AtPageUpperLeft{\color{CornflowerBlue!40}\rule[-0.2\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{0.2\paperheight}}
}%

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]